# Collectionview item position after scroll not displayed properly in iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I have implemented the collection view and used the 2 rows and 2 columns. First and second time data properly displayed after scrolling 3 and 4 times item positions not displayed properly. See the attached image with hidden product pictures.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:   (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return CGSizeMake(self.mainColview.frame.size.width/2-2, self.mainColview.frame.size.height/2-2);

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After disable the paging of collection view its working fine.